# Media Temple php.ini saving

Tags: twitter, php, mediatemple

So I am working on my client's website and in order to integrate twitter posts into the website I need to include the following line in PHP.ini:

```
allow_url_fopen = On;
```

So now my PHP.ini looks like this:

```
; Rename this file to php.ini and uncomment or add directives.
; For a complete list of valid directives, visit:
;  http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ini.php

[PHP]
; We highly recommend that you leave this options enabled
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1

; Increase maximum post size
;post_max_size = 20M

; Increase execution time
;max_execution_time = 300

; pull in EGPCS [Environment, GET, POST, Cookie, Server] variables as globals
;register_globals = true

; For performance reasons, (mt) does not load all of the modules that are available
; into PHP. You may uncomment any one of the following "extension" lines to enable
; the desired module

; Salblotron XSLT
;extension=xslt.so

; save in local tmp
session.save_path=/home/65994/data/tmp

allow_url_fopen = On;

upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

For some reason it works... but only for about 15 mins or so before it breaks and comes up with an error.

Nevertheless if I take the line added to php.ini and move it around... and resave, it works again...

ODD...

Does anyone know why or how to fix this?

Comment: I wouldn't use a PHP interface to Twitter, not while there is a Javascript one which would save you the server load...

Answer (score 0):

MT disables insecure php functions by default now, so there's a good chance that your issue may be due to something causing a timeout even though you've re-enabled the 'offensive' option. Try setting the

> default_socket_timeout

option to something longer http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

As an aside, you'll probably save yourself some grief if you switch to cURL with Twitter OAuth instead of direct url open.